# How to use google transliteration API using Key

Tags: google-translate, transliteration, google-translation-api

I want to use **google Transliteration API** for my website for transliterate script from one language to another (in my case English to Hindi). But I can't found any correct solution. I found it deprecated (https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started), but I want to use it whether I have to purchase it. I already have a **key** for google APIs but I can't get any perfect solution to use it for transliteration. Please provide me a solution or any alternate for using transliteration API.
Currently I'm using deprecated API but transliteration not working, and getting this error-

```
 jsapi:138 Loading "elements" other than "inputtools" is unsupported.
 cd @ jsapi:138

 jsapi:135 Uncaught Error: Must call google.charts.load before google.charts.setOnLoadCallback
    at Object.H.R [as setOnLoadCallback] (jsapi:135)
    at richedittransliteration:55
```

I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Thank you in advance.